# Multisite - passing ACF values from current site to Gravity Forms form from another site on multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, multisite, gravityforms

I'm trying to pass data from Advance Custom Fields into my Gravity Forms form. The problem I'm running into is that the form is being generated from another site on the multisite via:

```
<?php switch_to_blog(1);?>   
     <?php echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="3" title="false" 
     description="false"]' ); ?>
<?php restore_current_blog(); ?>
```

In my `functions.php` file (for both blog 1 and the current site), I have:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_lead_source_detail', 'populate_lead_source_detail' );
function populate_lead_source_detail( $value ) {

   $leadsourcedetail = get_field('lead_source_detail', $post->ID);
   return $leadsourcedetail;
}

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_lifecycle_status', 'populate_lifecycle_status' );
function populate_lifecycle_status( $value ) {
   $lifecycle = get_field('lifecycle_status', $post->ID);
   return $lifecycle;
}

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_lead_source', 'populate_lead_source' );
function populate_lead_source( $value ) {
   $leadsource = get_field('lead_source', $post->ID);
   return $leadsource;
}

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_channel', 'populate_channel' );
function populate_channel( $value ) {
   $channel = get_field('channel', $post->ID);
   return $channel;
}

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_expected_op_type', 'populate_expected_op_type' );
function populate_expected_op_type( $value ) {
   $expected = get_field('expected_op_type', $post->ID);
   return $expected;
}
```

The ACF fields work perfectly on blog 1, where the Gravity Form is being generated from, but I can't get them to pass the data to the form on the current current blog.

To make sure the ACF fields work (in general), I tested `<?php the_field(); ?>` for each of them, and the data is definitely there... so I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that I'm pulling the form from a different site on the multisite.

Anyone have any ideas on how to pass data from my current site to the blog 1 form? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went about this a completely different way. Found this in the Gravity Forms docs: https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-dynamic-population/ -- under shortcodes:

`[gravityform id=1 field_values=’parameter_name1=value1&parameter_name2=value2′]`

Wish I would've found this before I spent a whole day on this. Lol... Here were my steps after that:

1. I exported/imported the Gravity Form onto another site in the
   multisite that shared the same theme (so I wasn't working on two
   different `functions.php` files; this is why the blog id and Gravity Forms id are different below).
2. I removed all of the functions I originally created in the `functions.php`
   file that I stated earlier. (`populate_lead_source_detail`,
   `populate_lifecycle_status`, etc.)
3. I created variables from the ACF fields for that page.

   `<?php $lead_source_detail = get_field('lead_source_detail');
   $lifecycle_status = get_field('lifecycle_status');
   $lead_source = get_field('lead_source');
   $channel = get_field('channel');
   $expected_op_type = get_field('expected_op_type'); ?>`
4. I called the variables in the shortcode. (See below for my final code.)

   ```
                   <?php switch_to_blog(11);?>   

                       <?php echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false" field_values="lead_source_detail='.$lead_source_detail.'&lifecycle_status='.$lifecycle_status.'&lead_source='.$lead_source.'&channel='.$channel.'&expected_op_type='.$expected_op_type.'"]' ); ?>

                   <?php restore_current_blog(); ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Store your data using options and then try accessing it.

Site 1 --> Site1_only_plugin --> Site1_only_plugin_function()--> add_option( 'Site1_only_plugin_option', $var )

You should refer Brent Leavitt's comment in the below link. That is where I found this.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/

Probably this is what you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting way of going about it. I'll play around with that idea and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work this way. It kept trying to pull in info from blog 1 instead of the current blog - even with setting it in the options. Only way I got it to sorta work was if I put the exact numeric blog id in the function, but every site would be using information from whatever blog id I manually entered. I did figure it out a different way, though. Thanks anyway! :)